# Cannot figure out how to make a key spammer in python

Tags: python

I've been searching, testing, and so forth, and i cannot find a article to help me out.

I've tried over and over to get help, so i'm relying on stackoverflow to help me.

I'm wanting to make a spacebar spamming
but i need it to toggle when a key is pressed.
Kinda like this

```
if Key.F1:
   spacebar spammer
      if Key.F2:
          Spacebar spammer off
```

OBviously not correct, But in that sort.

Comment: What's a key spammer?

Comment: A "spammer" is something that sends that event as rapidly as possible.

Comment: Please show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If you're using Windows and just wanted a tool that does what you want, take a look at AutoHotKey: https://autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm

Comment: Where are you sending the keys to? A website? An app?